# Mousewheel fullpage scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a full page scroller when the mousewheel is used.  I have it directing to divs with the class of anchor.  The code wont work under normal circumstances but only when I have first clicked a link to the div so my url would be http://localhost/#test-anchor and then reload the page will the scroll function work.  Here is the code being used for experimentation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.anchor');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var div = 0; // current div
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < -10) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 100%);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you might want to take a look at Reveal.js: http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

Comment: can you elaborate? what doesn't work about it? what happens instead? Or add a [snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: the mousewheel scrolling acts normally.  only when it has a targeted div expressed in the url line does it work and only when the page is refreshed.    What I mean by that is I had links that direct to different divs on the site.  If I have first clicked on one of those and refresh the page then it will work

Comment: Is the event triggered when it doesn't work or not at all ?

Comment: yes it is being triggered.  it seems that it will only activate if the page has been loaded through a id target reference